# How can I pass arguments via Launch.json for debugging in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python, json, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to migrate over from Visual Studio Code to Visual Studio 2017. I do not have a project or solution for my code, rather a main.py file is launched with set arguments in order to run.

I have the current code in my launch.json file

```
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "project": "project\\myproject\\main.py",
      "name": "MyDebug:Debug",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "pythonPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\custom\\python.exe",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\project\\myproject\\main.py",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",      
      "args": [
        "C:\\Users\\Me\\mytextdoc.txt",
        "-l",
        "DEBUG"
      ]
    },
```

When I select MyDebug from the Debug dropdown list, the startup item is correctly set as main.py. However, my arguments are not used.passed when main.py is called.

This code has been pulled from a Visual Studio Code environment and largely unchanged (i.e. "console": "integratedTerminal").

How am I able to pass arguments in Visual Studio 2019?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/quickstart-05-python-visual-studio-open-folder?view=vs-2019)?

Using Open Folder mode in VS

1. Right-click the Python (.py) startup file in Solution Explorer choose "Set as Startup Item"
2. Right-click the Python (.py) startup file in Solution Explorer and select Debug and Launch Settings.
3. Choose Default Debugger

this will create a launch.vs.json file like this

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "python",
      "interpreter": "(default)",
      "interpreterArguments": "",
      "scriptArguments": "",
      "env": {},
      "nativeDebug": false,
      "webBrowserUrl": "",
      "project": "python3\\contemplate_koans.py",
      "name": "contemplate_koans.py",
      "workingDirectory": "python3"
    }
  ]
}
```

4. Edit "scriptArguments"

Comment: This is the best answer. "Visual Studio" doesn't work the same way as "Visual Studio Code" (at all). Arguments should be set in the scriptArguments property of the launch.vs.json file as a single string (like in a commande line).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was able to port the definitions from launch.json to launch.vs.json following [Open and run Python code in a folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/quickstart-05-python-visual-studio-open-folder?view=vs-2019) , but I remained with the problem that scriptArguments is a string instead of an array as args, and using args doesn't work. This is extremely annoying because a single string with all the arguments may turn to be very long, and the settings file becomes difficult to manage (a very long arguments string that you cannot break in the json file). Does anyone have a better solution for this? scriptArguments alternatives?

thanks,
Emanuel